# Having trouble solving a simple Python Payroll program in Python 3.X

Tags: python-3.x

This is the problem.

Write a program to solve a simple payroll calculation. Find the amount of pay given, hours worked, and hourly rate. (The formula to calculate payroll is pay = hourly rate * hours worked.)

[What i have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rysuR.png)
    def hours():
    hours = input("how many hours did you work?: ")
    return hours

```
def rate():
rate= input("How much is your hourly rate?: ")

def grossPay():
grossPay = hours() * rate()
return grossPay

def main():
print("your gross pay is"), + (grossPay)
return grossPay

def main():
print('Payroll Information')
print hours()
print rate()

main()
```

Comment: Please include your code (as text, not an image) in the question itself. If the link were to go down, your question would become unanswerable. You should also describe (with specifics!) what issues you're having with your current code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am a total newbie here and was just seeking advice on what was wrong. I edited the question to contain the code.

Comment: You're defining `main` twice. Also, your indentation is way off in the question now, please fix your code formatting (also the first few lines are outside the code format block). What do you mean by "what was wrong?" What makes you think something's wrong? Please read *carefully* [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code...

- You have no indentation in your code, which is required for Python (though you may have just pasted it into SO incorrectly)
- You call the hours function, but one doesn't exist in your code blurb
- Opinion: Seems needlessly complex for a simple operation

There are many ways to do this, but putting it all into one function is most natural to me. I'd do something like this...

```
def calc_and_show_pay():
    rate = input("How much is your hourly rate?: ")     #collect the hourly rate
    hours = input("How many hours did you work?: ")     #collect number of hours worked
    gross_pay = float(rate) * float(hours)  #Convert string input to floats so we can do math on it
    print("Payroll Information:")           #print out results, per your format in the example
    print("Your pay is %f"%(gross_pay))     #could also do print("your pay is:", gross_pay)
    return gross_pay    #you don't need to return this unless you want to use this number elsewhere (i.e., you have a bigger program where you'll use this as an input somewhere else).
```

Then of course you can call "calc_and_show_pay()" as you please.

Comment: Wow I feel super slow right now. For some reason I was trying to do more than what was required smh thanks so much for your help and all that is contained in the comments block. I see what they mean when they say don't make it harder than what it is because its really not.